# Can we store brackets into a PHP variable to get the value of array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, brackets, square-bracket

I want to store square bracket string in a variable so that I can use that variable to get the value of array. How can I do that?

Example:

```
$vehicle = array("car"=>"volvo","bike"=>"polygon");

$bracket1="['car']";

$bracket2="['bike']";

echo $vehicle.$bracket1;//my expected result = 'volvo';

echo $vehicle.$bracket2;//my expected result = 'polygon';
```

Case
Suppose I have this data

```
$data = array(
"vehicles"=>array(
    array(
        "name"=>"volvo",
        "manufacturer"=>"abc",
        "color"=>array("blue"=>"wonderful","red"=>"fantastic")),
    array(
        "name"=>"toyota",
        "manufacturer"=>"def",
        "color"=>array("blue"=>"awesome","red"=>"good")),
    array(
        "name"=>"mecedes",
        "manufacturer"=>"ghi",
        "color"=>array("blue"=>"nice","red"=>"great","green"=>"good","brown"=>"elegant")),
));

$fields  = array(
    "$data['vehicles']['name']",
    "$data['vehicles']['manufacturer']",
    "$data['vehicles']['color']['blue']",
    "$data['vehicles']['color']['red']"
);

//a function to print those data according to user parameter($fields, it may uncertain pattern)

function get_data($data,$fields){
    for($c=0;$c<count($data);$c++){
        foreach($fields as $field){     //field to show
            echo $field;
        }
    }
}
```

edited:

```
$data = array(
"vehicles"=>array(
    array(
        "name"=>"volvo",
        "manufacturer"=>"abc",
        "color"=>array("blue"=>"wonderful","red"=>"fantastic")),
    array(
        "name"=>"toyota",
        "manufacturer"=>"def",
        "color"=>array("blue"=>"awesome","red"=>"good")),
    array(
        "name"=>"mecedes",
        "manufacturer"=>"ghi",
        "color"=>array("blue"=>"nice","red"=>"great","green"=>"good","brown"=>"elegant")),
));

$c=0;

$fields  = array( // note added zeros here... these are your "vehicle" array key

    "{$data['vehicles'][$c]['name']}",

    "{$data['vehicles'][$c]['manufacturer']}",

    "{$data['vehicles'][$c]['color']['blue']}",

    "{$data['vehicles'][$c]['color']['red']}"

);


for($c=0;$c<count($data['vehicles']);$c++){

    foreach($fields as $field) {

        echo $field . PHP_EOL;

    }

}

//the output print : volvo abc wonderful fantastic volvo abc wonderful fantastic volvo abc wonderful fantastic 

//the output expectetd : volvo abc wonderful fantastic toyota dev awesome good mercedes ghi nice great
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try this:

```
$vehicle = array("car" => "volvo", "bike" => "polygon");

$bracket1 = "car";

$bracket2 = "bike";

echo $vehicle[$bracket1]; //my expected result = 'volvo';

echo $vehicle[$bracket2]; //my expected result = 'polygon';
```

**Edit**: you want a function that does this... You don't need it. This is a basic PHP language construct.

Anywho, here's your function (wrapping that basic PHP language construct up in an extra layer) - I'll even throw in a basic error check (return false if the array key doesn't exist):

```
function searchMyHugeArrayForSomething($huge_array, $something) {
    if(!array_key_exists($something, $huge_array))
        return false; // return false if array key doesn't exist
    return $huge_array[$something]; // return your desired result......
}
```

Demo:

```
$my_huge_array = array(
    'pet' => 'cat',
    'wife' => 'sarah',
    'brother' => 'john'
    // etc
);

echo searchMyHugeArrayForSomething($my_huge_array, 'wife'); // sarah
echo searchMyHugeArrayForSomething($my_huge_array, 'husband'); // returns false (oop, sexist!)
echo searchMyHugeArrayForSomething($my_huge_array, 'brother'); // john
// etc............?
```

Make sense?

**Edit**: OK, multidimensional array is very different (your original question was flat). You are having an issue here because you're missing a level in between `vehicles` and `name`, etc. There's an array there containing numeric indexes, so your path would **actually** be `$data['vehicles'][0]['name']` - and when that's the case, you can basically just `echo` each line of your array to get the value of the array key parsed into a string.

In this example I've added both curly braces to each line to parse as a [variable variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php),  and because your example won't actually run as it is (it's trying to parse the array keys as a variable and syntactically failing), and added the zero array key. You'll need to work out which array key you want to target yourself, this is just using the first:

```
$fields  = array( // note added zeros here... these are your "vehicle" array key
    "{$data['vehicles'][0]['name']}",
    "{$data['vehicles'][0]['manufacturer']}",
    "{$data['vehicles'][0]['color']['blue']}",
    "{$data['vehicles'][0]['color']['red']}"
);

foreach($fields as $field) {
    echo $field . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Output:**

```
volvo
abc
wonderful
fantastic
```

Comment: because I the variable will be uncertain pattern exp:

Comment: I've tried a few scenarios using your example with variable variables and can't see any way that it will work. If you could provide some cases where the method above won't work I can provide you some solutions for them - this **is** the basic framework for how to use associative arrays, error checking for unexpected keys, undefined keys, etc should be added in on top of this layer.

Comment: if your data structure is utterly arbitrary and can't be predicted in advance, then perhaps your basic design needs to be rethought from the ground up.

Comment: @scrowler, I have a huge array. I want to select which value to display. So I need a function that accept the huge array as parameter 1, and an array that contain which value to display as parameter 2

Comment: @user3117522 you mean: `$your_huge_array[$value_to_display]` where `$value_to_display = 'yourArrayKey';` ?

Comment: @user3117522 I've updated my answer to include a function that wraps this up. You really don't need it, but here it is anyway.

Comment: @scrowler thank you for your sample. I have edit my question, I add a sample

Comment: @user3117522 updated answer - you're missing a step in your data integrity and you'll need to address it before you can progress any further

Comment: how can we travers the $data['vehicles'] to get all the rows ?     foreach($c=0;$c<count($data['vehicles'])$c++)  {  foreach($fields as $field){  echo $field;  }  }

Comment: it prints only first row  , the 0 index of the vehicles

Comment: As I say, you'll need to be more specific with your array or variable names

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense at all. You can't embed variables in a string before you use them - and why you would even want to do this is equally as important. You need to stop, have a think about what you are trying to achieve and think of a better way to do it that what you are currently attempting. You're quickly heading down a rabbit hole with no return...